# PHP: curl postfield parameters are not showing in return of target url

Tags: php, curl, php-5.3

I have used curl in php and set parameter in "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS". And I use return $_REQUEST/$_POST on the target url for checking my passed parameter are posted correctly. But I am not able to check the posted parameter in target page.

**Example of target url:-** http://www.eg.com/target

> > curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.eg.com/target");

CODE

```
$clientId = "AXLAatA9ucEkGt2C9y5SuNRd24Ys4NPod8VJmNNFq5otso1RQRIn";
        $secret = "EGOojWJihcU8wnGTVQivKOsD_ylB5mMdaWmbn_1UWGlqbaugSCOZ";
        $post = array(
                        "key" =>  $clientId,
                        "secret" => $secret   
                    );

        $ipnexec = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.eg.com/target"); 
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $ipnresult = curl_exec($ipnexec);
        $result = json_decode($ipnresult);
```

Any helps !!

Regards
Patrick

Comment: Please post your whole CURL code.

Comment: Please post the relevant code of /target as well.

Comment: @all Thanks for replying.I update code on my query please check it.

Comment: So you do not have access to the endpoint you are trying to hit? That makes it awefully hard to work with if you aren't getting any errors. You might want to start by setting the following header to ensure that the recipient is getting what they need.

    curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    [
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do have access to the endpoint at http://www.eg.com/target, you need to change the stream used. $_REQUEST is for form encoded data only. To access raw json, you need to use

`$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`

And then if you want to "overwrite $_POST, use

`$_POST = json_decode($data, true);`